# Update event in full calendar not saving to database

Tags: php, sql-update, fullcalendar

i am trying to update my events to a different date/time however the updated event is not saving the start time and date and end time and date to the database

THIS IS MY CALENDAR PAGE

```html
 eventDrop: function (event, delta) {
             var dstart = $.fullCalendar.moment(event.start).format();
                var dend = $.fullCalendar.moment(event.end).format();
                  console.log("Event Triggered");
                console.log(dstart);
                console.log(dend);
                    //var start = ($.formatDate(event.start, "Y-MM-DD"));
                   // var end = ($.formatDate(event.end, "Y-MM-DD"));
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'update_roster.php',
                        data:  {
                        title: event.title,
                        start: dstart,
                        end: dend
                        //url: url
                    },
                        type: "POST",
                        success: function (response) {
                            displayMessage("Updated Successfully");
                        }
                    });
                }
```

THIS IS THE UPDATE EVENT PAGE

```html
<?php
require_once "config.php";

$id = $_POST['id'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$start = $_POST['start'];
$end = $_POST['end'];

$sqlUpdate = "UPDATE roster SET title='" . $title . "',start='" . $start . "',end='" . $end . "' WHERE id=" . $id;

mysqli_query($conn, $sqlUpdate);
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated as i have been looking for a solution to this code for 2 days

Comment: are start and end column have datetime type in your database

Comment: yes the start and end column are both datetime type

Comment: can you show start content with `print $start`  then you will see if its date format or not

Comment: Event Triggered roster.php:138:19
2019-01-02T16:30:00 roster.php:139:17

Answer (score -1):

ok great try use this code use date_create and format :

```
<?php
 require_once "config.php";

  $id = $_POST['id'];
  $title = $_POST['title'];
  $start = $_POST['start'];
  $end = $_POST['end'];
  $start=date_create($start);
  $end =date_create($end);
 $sqlUpdate = "UPDATE roster SET start='" . $start->format('Y-m-d h:i:s') . "',end='" . $end->format('Y-m-d h:i:s') ."' WHERE title='" . $title."'";

$result=  mysqli_query($conn, $sqlUpdate) or die(mysqli_error($conn));;
  mysqli_close($conn);

  ?>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186212/discussion-on-answer-by-hamzanig-update-event-in-full-calendar-not-saving-to-dat).